# Convert / Create ML models to iOS and Android

Tags: android, ios, machine-learning, firebase-mlkit

I am new in `ML` world and I use `CreateML` and `Turi Create` as a iOS Developer to make `mlmodels`. From a quick research I found that `ML Kit` provide a solution for `iOS` and `Android`. Is there any other solution that can convert or create `Machine Learning Models` for both platforms (iOS and Android) ?

Thanks